# What the heck am I doing wrong with this php script?

Tags: php

For the life of me, I can't figure out where I'm going wrong with this script.  It just displays a blank screen.  I've got this installed on a joomla 1.5 site with this code in Jumi component.  Is it the code or Jumi/Joomla?  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!   Thanks.

```
    <html>
    <head>

    <?php


    // RETURN LIST OF DATA ROWS
    function getItems($query) {

        // Initialize variables
                $result = null;

        // Get a reference to the database
                $db = &JFactory::getDBO();
        // Get Current User
                $user = &JFactory::getUser();
            $user_email = $user->email;

        // Set the Query 
    $query ="SELECT *  FROM my_table WHERE owneremail = '$user_email'";

        $num=mysql_numrows($result);

    mysql_close();
    ?>

    </head>

    <body>
    // REPLACE TEMPLATE FIELDS WITH ACTUAL VALUES

    <?php
      $i=0;
      while ($i < $num){

            $f1=mysql_result($result,"firstname");   
            $f2=mysql_result($result,"lastname");
            $f3=mysql_result($result,"street_num");
            $f4=mysql_result($result,"street");
            $f5=mysql_result($result,"apt");
            $f6=mysql_result($result,"city");
            $f7=mysql_result($result,"postcode");
    }

    ?>

<div>
<div style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><p><strong>Customer Welcome Letter</strong></p>
</div>
'<div style="line-height:15px;"><p><strong>Hello  <?php echo $f1; ?> <?php echo $f2; ?></strong> <br>
<br>
<strong>Here are your details: <span style="border: 1px dashed #CFF; padding-left: 6px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-right: 3px; padding-top: 3px; background-color: #FFC;"><?php echo $f3; ?> <?php echo $f4; ?> <?php echo $f5; ?> <?php echo $f6; ?>, CO <?php echo $f7; ?></span></strong>(AKA..“<strong>User</strong>”).  </p>

</div>

    <?php
    $i++;
    }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We tried really hard, but we don't know `what the heck are you doing wrong with this php script`.

Comment: Maybe its applicable or not but you dont have a DOCTYPE in there.

Comment: That's a pretty lazy question. I'm shure you can at least work out if it's a fatal misconfiguration (is at least the `<head>` sent to the browser) or if something is wrong with your database query (is the `while` loop ever called?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `getItems` you never actually execute the sql statement `$query`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a standard PHP code which sends out e-mails, apparently to users in the database. It has nothing to do with Joomla or any framework, as this script uses pretty standard, basic elements only.